# Is there a way to have access to Mui state classes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I like the way to styles mui-components with there class names. Is there is a way to access the state classes like `Mui-checked` with a variable.

I will get more in detail:

I have a styled component which is looks like this:

```js
import { Switch, type SwitchProps, styled, switchClasses } from "@mui/material";
...

type SwitchExtraProps<P = {}> = P & {};

const StyledSwitch = styled(Switch)<SwitchExtraProps<SwitchProps>>(() => ({
    ...
    "&:active": {
        [`& .${switchClasses.thumb}`]: {
            width: 15,
        },
        [`& .${switchClasses.switchBase}.Mui-checked`]: {
            transform: "translateX(9px)",
        },
    },
    ...
}));

export default StyledSwitch;
```

What I prefer is that Mui-checked would be looks like this:

```js
[`& .${switchClasses.switchBase}.${muiClasses.checked}`]
```

Do anyone knows what i have to import to get access to this?

Thank you.

I looked into the different files of Mui but did not found something. Same in the Mui-Docs and google is not helpfull with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find their exports and decided to create my own

```
import { generateUtilityClasses } from '@mui/material'

const muiClasses = generateUtilityClasses('', [
    'active',
    'checked',
    'completed',
    'disabled',
    'error',
    'expanded',
    'focused',
    'focusVisible',
    'required',
    'selected',
])
```

if you want type safety, you can add type to that array via `GlobalStateSlot` from mui